# Rotate individual letters of the same word in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, captcha

I'm generating CAPTCHAs for training data and I have a pretty good ImageMagick script going already.

However, one thing I really want is for individual letters of the word to be slightly rotated, see for example this reCAPTCHA:

[image]

Is there an easy (or hard) way to accomplish this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
#!/bin/bash
word="theId"
for (( i=0 ; i<${#word} ; i++ )) ; do
   rotation=$(((RANDOM%10)*4))           # Generate random rotation for each letter
   convert -background none -virtual-pixel none -pointsize 72 label:"${word:i:1}" +distort SRT $rotation miff:-
done | convert -background none - +append result.png
```

[image]

Basically I am creating and rotating one letter at a time and writing them to a `MIFF` stream, one after the other, and at the end, I am using `+append` to join together everything I see on the input stream.

If you want to *scrunch the letters closer together* (TM) you can add `-trim +repage` just before `miff:-`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I went with a similar approach. Some tips if anyone ever finds this, I'm using -undercolor white to make them line up vertically the right amount, then trimming. Good answer!

Comment: @pjreddie: it would be nice if you added your finally used approach in an answer of your own. How exactly did you use `-undercolor white` to line up the letters vertically?